# C++ pointer with the right address but with another random value?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, vector

I'm doing this over Qt but I don't think it matters since it's just classes (though one of them is a Thread Class).

Anyways, the point is that I have a Vector in my main function and I'm trying to pass it to a pointer in another class but the problem is that, in that class, I get random values.
I compared the addresses, the one pointed by the pointer and the main vector's address, and they are identical which means that the sharing part is working just fine but for some reason I get different values.
After googling for hours I realized that since my vector is on the stack it will be automatically removed on a return which is logical and that could be the thing causing this problem so I've decided to use "new" to declare my main vector in heap:

```
vector<int> * ids = new vector<int>;
```

and I got a double public pointer in the other class

```
vector<int> ** ids;
```

and I appended the address of the main vector to it.
After comparing the addresses, they're the same so I knew that what I'm doing is mostly right but for some reason I still get random values.

What could be the problem? I feel like I'm doing a stupid mistake somewhere but I'm tired of thinking today so it would be great if you could give me a hand here.

**EDIT: (ADDED SOURCE)**

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QtCore>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class get_clients : public QThread
{
public:
    vector<SOCKET> **clients;
    void run() {
        cout << (*clients)->size() << endl;
    }
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    vector<SOCKET> * clients = new vector<SOCKET>();

    get_clients * get_clients1 = new get_clients();
    get_clients1->clients = &clients;
    get_clients1->start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to supply more code

Comment: Why a pointer to a pointer? I guess you are dereferencing part of the object and thats why you get this behaviour. Try a single pointer in the other class.

Comment: James, it's basically just this, there's nothing else to supply, except for the shape of the class or something.

Comment: fassl, I am using a pointer in the main because, as far as I googled, having the vector in heap would solve this problem, and to access that vector pointer I need a double pointer in the other class and that is why I'm doing this. The reason I'm using pointers in the first place is because I want to use the vector itself and not a copy of it.

Comment: You don't need a double pointer in the other class

Comment: Take  a look at the source please, I just added it, and let me know what's wrong.

Comment: I am not saying it is wrong, but you don't need it. You can let the **clients be *clients and and assign it like ->clients = clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here it is:
I basically had this important part of the code

```
vector<SOCKET> * clients = new vector<SOCKET>();

get_clients * get_clients1 = new get_clients();
get_clients1->clients = &clients;
get_clients1->start();
```

shoved in the constructor of the class which was sadly getting removed automatically for some reason, it shouldn't though, but I believe it's some problem with my own code.

The answer to everything here is to know this small difference between the Stack and the Heap; whenever a function, for example, declares a variable in the Stack then that variable will be removed from the Stack right after that function returns/finishes, but, when it comes to the Heap, that variable won't be removed unless you removed it yourself (using free for example) or the whole process ended.
So if you want your variable to last, when working with classes in c++, then it would be a good idea to declare that variable in the Stack as a Private variable(better) or simply declare it in the Heap wherever you want.

Comment: You absolutely must understand why this fix work. Otherwise it's cargo cult programming.

Comment: I just improved the answer and I think that it should be more than enough to whoever is facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You must be doing something wrong. Post more code.
You need to make sure your pointer points to your list before iterating through it.
This is an example of what you are trying to do and it works perfectly:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int>* myList = new std::vector<int>();


    std::vector<int>** myListPtr = &myList;

    (*myListPtr)->push_back(12);
    myList->push_back(13);

    for (auto& itm : *myList)
    {
        std::cout << itm << " address of item: " << &itm << std::endl;
    }

    for (auto& itm : **myListPtr)
    {
        std::cout << itm << " address of item: " << &itm << std::endl;
    }

    delete myList;
    myListPtr = nullptr;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```